# Highcharts: Y axis max value should be greater than the data point

Tags: highcharts

For Highcharts, I want the y-axis max value to be slightly greater than the max data point but it should never exceed "100".

I tried setting max =100, the problem is whenever the data point is too small like say 12, the line is pushed down. In this case the max value should not be 100 but slightly greater than 12.

here's a small snippet.
https://codepen.io/thushara07/pen/qQWjZG

`maxPadding: 0.1,
      endOnTick: false,`

expected: Max value should be greater than the max data point but it should never exceed 100.

Answer (score 0):

In the `load` chart event you can check the axis `max` property and use `setExtremes`, if it is necessary:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

            if (yAxis.max > 100) {
                yAxis.setExtremes(null, 100, true, false);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/moyr4xec/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes